# C++ crossplatform UI framework for both Mac and Win?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, macos

I'm looking for an UI framework that will let me create a C++ application looking/behaving native on both mac and win. By native I mean the approach similar to, say, IBM's AWT/SWT on Java.

Six years ago there was no such thing around, is there something now?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There you go! Four responses, one answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt and wxWidgets are good. But as far as I know, there is really no library that gives a entirely native look and feel.
If it is really important, I suggest you create a native application for each system and factor out the common code.

Answer (score 5):

Qt and wxWidgets come to mind. A word of advice if I may: Mac OS X users have a set of expectations when it comes to UI, most of which are detailed in Apple’s Human Interface Guidelines. Cross-platform applications tend to look-and-feel and behave differently from native applications, and users will look for and prefer native alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You may wan to look at at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) which is

- free (in the various definitions of term)
- very well documented
- cross platform with good support on Windows, Linux, OS X, phones, and more

and e.g. [here is a tutorial on making it look native](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/learning/online/talks/developerdays2009/tech-talks/how-to-make-your-qt-application-look-native/)  on the host system.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/), it is free for non-commercial use and I believe the commercial license is around $2000.  Another popular library is wxWidgets

Comment: It's also free for commercial open source use.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Qt from Nokia](http://qt.nokia.com/).