# Building Cross Platform (Mac/PC) Apps?

Tags: cocoa, macos, cross-platform

I want to spec out an app and it is necessary for it to be accessible for both Macs and PCs.  I previously would have thought of using Adobe Air however my opinion is that it is to slow,  much slower than native apps.

What other options exist.  I am willing to forsake a bit of speed but don't want to handicap the application by choosing the wrong framework/platform.

I will be hiring out this project so I will find a programmer that understands teh suggested approach.

Comment: Depends on how complex the app needs to be.  Java works on both platforms.  If your app is not too complex, you could try Titanium: http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/

Comment: There’s another Stack Overflow question about Mac OS X/Windows cross-platform UI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580772/c-crossplatform-ui-framework-for-both-mac-and-win/

Comment: What will the application do? What is your intended audience? There's a pretty wide range of tolerance among audiences to "non-native" feeling applications, and an increasingly gigantic number of cross-platform options.

Answer (score 0):

If you go for cross platform solution like Adobe Air ... Java ... Mono ... Qt (framework) etc ... I don't think so will ever be able get the native efficiency ..

In my resent observation products like DropBox use python for its core modules and do native implementation based on needs.

My call for you is --- if you need best posible native app efficiency and cross platform  then go for hybrid --- develop app's core module using may be python then go for native solution in rest of the places.